# Why are the AudioServices used to vibrate an iphone?

Tags: iphone

Is the only way to vibrate an iphone using the AudioServices?

If so, why was it run through Audio to vibrate the device?

Answer (score 1):

One usually associates vibrations synonymous with audio/alerts (System Alerts, Text Messages, receiving a call). As this is done through the Audio Services it makes sense to also be able to make the phone vibrate this way.

> why was it run through Audio to vibrate the device

Just to point out, it's not vibrating the device using the soundwaves made by playing audio.

Comment: hahaha, Reallllllllllly. bad wording on "run" . should be implemented through, but you knew that.

Comment: My original point still stands. I usually consider vibrations synonymous with Audio (with regards to mobile platforms) so I guess that why's its in AudioServices